# TestNG iterate over test data instead of test methods

Tags: java, testng

When using DataProvider with multiple TestNG methods, every method is run with all data sets in sequence. Instead I want to iterate over the data sets and execute all methods on each iteration.
I do not care if the results show every single test method result or a summary of the runs per method.

I already tried the option

```
order-by-instances="true"
```

in a suite.xml with no success.

Sample code:

```
public class TestNGTest
{
    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public Object[][] createData(Method m) {
      return new Object[][] { new Object[] { "Cedric" }, new Object[] {"Martina"}};
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp")    
    public void test1(String s) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("test1 " + s);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
    public void test2(String s) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("test2 " + s);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Actual result:

```
test1 Cedric
test1 Martina
test2 Cedric
test2 Martina
PASSED: test1("Cedric")
PASSED: test1("Martina")
PASSED: test2("Cedric")
PASSED: test2("Martina")
```

Wanted result:

```
test1 Cedric
test2 Cedric
test1 Martina
test2 Martina
PASSED: test1("Cedric")
PASSED: test2("Cedric")
PASSED: test1("Martina")
PASSED: test2("Martina")
```

Comment: Just a question: why do you want to do that?

Comment: In my case the data sets represent states which need to be set up and torn down. Imagine this being user login credentials and you want to test log in and log out for each user. Instead of one test like logInAndOut you can now have separate test methods that all operate on one user account.

Comment: That may be just me, but I do not like losing the independence of tests.  These tests seem to be just test _steps_ then.  I would rather put the details of each step into helper methods and then have the tests call them step by step.

Comment: That's right. Those are steps. The problem with doing all steps in one @Test is that whatever fails, the whole test fails and you need to dig into the stack traces to get hints about what went wrong. While this is ok for unit tests that are white-box, for black-box testing having one status per step is much more verbose. If a product owner sees in Jenkins/Bamboo that "Test X fails at step Y with test data Z" then he can probably better understand that than "Test X failed" every time. While that doesn't replace verbose error messages, it does add details to the results.

Comment: I should also add that I'm mostly automating tests that are defined for humans and are executable without automation too. So most of them consist of steps that depend on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with following listener GroupByInstanceEnabler. You can put this listener in Listeners  annotation in your test  class (or test base class if have such) or just even simpler and  better solution is to put it in META-INF  to let TestNg load it using ServiceLoader (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-service-loader)

This will allow you to get rid of suite.xml and only what you will need to keep this META-INF and enabler on your classpath. Anytime you will run any test this will be loaded - not need to configure anything like IDE,  create suites to run - it always will load your listener out-of-the-box.

```
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteListener;

public class GroupByInstanceEnabler implements ISuiteListener {

    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
        suite.getXmlSuite().setGroupByInstances(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {

    }
}
```

Pawel

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This indeed is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using Factory, DataProvider and an injected XmlTest object.

Of course, the TestClass can be in another file. I prefer to keep it as an inner class however, because it can't be run without the factory anyways. The only downside of this solution is that you can't run single tests from the class.

```
package com.nhp.ts.test.business.qi;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

public class FooTest {

    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public Object[][] createData() {
        return new Object[][] {
            { "Cedric" },
            { "Martina" }
        };
    }

    @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
    public TestClass[] testFactory(String name) {
        return new TestClass[] { new TestClass(name) };
    }

    public class TestClass {

        private String name;

        public TestClass(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @BeforeTest
        public void setOptions(XmlTest test)
        {
            test.setGroupByInstances(true);
        }

        @Test
        public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("test1 " + name);
        }

        @Test
        public void test2() throws InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("test2 " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's exactly the same as add 'group-by-instance="true"' into '<test>' tag.

Comment: You're right, the effect is the same. But with this approach you need no suite.xml. At the time I asked the question I also had no idea about Factory.

Comment: So the better is to use suite xml or [solution by Pawel Kowalski](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26800125/1039742)

Comment: I tested the same exact code and I am getting this error:-  testngExamples.FooTest.testFactory MUST return [ java.lang.Object[] or org.testng.IInstanceInfo[] ] but returns [LtestngExamples.FooTest$TestClass;